# How does talib calculate RSI (Relative Strength Index)?

Tags: python

Is there anybody who knows how talib, which is a library for financial techniqual analysis in Python, calculates Relative Strength Index (RSI)?

There are different ways to calculate RSI, depending on whether you use simple averaging or exponential smoothing. I have played around with all of them, but have not been able to figure out how talib calculates RSI.

Here are some different approaches that I tried to calculate RSI:

My data is pd["close"], which is a pandas.core.series.Series:

```
{Timestamp('2016-01-04 00:00:00'): 54.79999923706055,
 Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00'): 55.04999923706055,
 Timestamp('2016-01-06 00:00:00'): 54.04999923706055,
 Timestamp('2016-01-07 00:00:00'): 52.16999816894531,
 Timestamp('2016-01-08 00:00:00'): 52.33000183105469,
 Timestamp('2016-01-11 00:00:00'): 52.29999923706055,
 Timestamp('2016-01-12 00:00:00'): 52.779998779296875,
 Timestamp('2016-01-13 00:00:00'): 51.63999938964844,
 Timestamp('2016-01-14 00:00:00'): 53.11000061035156,
 Timestamp('2016-01-15 00:00:00'): 50.9900016784668,
 Timestamp('2016-01-19 00:00:00'): 50.560001373291016,
 Timestamp('2016-01-20 00:00:00'): 50.790000915527344,
 Timestamp('2016-01-21 00:00:00'): 50.47999954223633,
 Timestamp('2016-01-22 00:00:00'): 52.290000915527344,
 Timestamp('2016-01-25 00:00:00'): 51.790000915527344,
 Timestamp('2016-01-26 00:00:00'): 52.16999816894531,
 Timestamp('2016-01-27 00:00:00'): 51.220001220703125,
 Timestamp('2016-01-28 00:00:00'): 52.060001373291016,
 Timestamp('2016-01-29 00:00:00'): 55.09000015258789,
 Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): 54.709999084472656,
 Timestamp('2016-02-02 00:00:00'): 53.0,
 Timestamp('2016-02-03 00:00:00'): 52.15999984741211,
 Timestamp('2016-02-04 00:00:00'): 52.0,
 Timestamp('2016-02-05 00:00:00'): 50.15999984741211,
 Timestamp('2016-02-08 00:00:00'): 49.40999984741211,
 Timestamp('2016-02-09 00:00:00'): 49.279998779296875,
 Timestamp('2016-02-10 00:00:00'): 49.709999084472656,
 Timestamp('2016-02-11 00:00:00'): 49.689998626708984,
 Timestamp('2016-02-12 00:00:00'): 50.5,
 Timestamp('2016-02-16 00:00:00'): 51.09000015258789}
```

1. With simple averaging:

```
period = 14
close_delta = pd['close'].diff()
up = close_delta.clip(lower=0)
down = -1 * close_delta.clip(upper=0)

AvgU = up.rolling(window = period).mean()
AvgD = down.rolling(window = period).mean()

rs = AvgU / AvgD
rsi_simple = 100 - (100/(1 + rs))
rsi_simple_np = np.array(rsi_simple)
rsi_simple_np


Result from approach 1: 
array([        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan, 37.25657906,
       37.93970034, 38.09925461, 49.49310243, 60.05830482, 58.56432322,
       50.71895845, 51.7333353 , 45.94594218, 46.90528681, 45.81208345,
       44.4607394 , 47.19999756, 39.13042092, 44.74327111, 45.67308471])
```

2. With Exponential Weighting:

```
period = 14
close_delta = pd['close'].diff()
up = close_delta.clip(lower=0)
down = -1 * close_delta.clip(upper=0)
up_ewm = up.ewm(com = period-1, min_periods = period).mean()
down_ewm = down.ewm(com = period-1, min_periods = period).mean()

rs_ewm = up_ewm / down_ewm
rsi_ewm = 100 - (100/(1 + rs_ewm))
rsi_ewm_np

Result from approach 2:
array([        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan, 41.95958341,
       44.87716279, 39.52759183, 45.69209969, 61.09733337, 58.84295505,
       49.9171034 , 46.20901506, 45.51545438, 38.38105197, 35.91021116,
       35.4838002 , 38.10194654, 38.02465245, 43.06231841, 46.47516513])
```

3. With talib.RSI

```
talib_rsi = talib.RSI(pd["close"], timeperiod=14))

The result from approach 3

array([        nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,         nan,
               nan,         nan,         nan,         nan, 37.25657906,
       39.35788483, 36.10262076, 40.76765901, 53.8548396 , 52.29432162,
       45.85517725, 43.05088129, 42.51751177, 36.86159232, 34.82787565,
       34.47284663, 36.76885993, 36.70443892, 41.1978013 , 44.29955905])
```

Answer (score 0):

They use SMMA. I believe they do this to save computing time.

#Import everything and get data

```
    import yfinance as yf
    import talib as ta

    ticker = yf.Ticker("BTC-USD")
    period = '10y' 
    interval = '1d' 
    data = ticker.history(interval=interval, period= period)
    df = data[['Close']].copy()
    df['Change'] = df['Close'] - df['Close'].shift(1)
    df = df.reset_index()
    df = df.rename(columns={"index": "Date"})
```

#Get SMMA RSI, could use some cleaning but the results are correct

```
    RSI_X = 14
    RSI_X2 = RSI_X - 1
    RSI_X3 = RSI_X + 1

    df['Upward_Movement'] = 0
    df.loc[df['Change'] >= 0, 'Upward_Movement'] = df['Change']
    df['Downward_Movement'] = 0
    df.loc[df['Change'] < 0, 'Downward_Movement'] = abs(df['Change'])
    
    df['Upward_Movement_SMA'] = df['Upward_Movement'].rolling(RSI_X).mean()
    df['Downward_Movement_SMA'] = df['Downward_Movement'].rolling(RSI_X).mean()

    df['Upward_Movement_SMMA'] = 0
    df['Upward_Movement_SMMA'].iloc[RSI_X:RSI_X3] = df['Upward_Movement_SMA'] 
    df['Downward_Movement_SMMA'] = 0
    df['Downward_Movement_SMMA'].iloc[RSI_X:RSI_X3] = df['Downward_Movement_SMA']

    for index, row in df.iloc[RSI_X3:].iterrows():
        df['Upward_Movement_SMMA'].iloc[RSI_X3:] = ((df['Upward_Movement_SMMA'].shift(1)*RSI_X2)+df['Upward_Movement'])/RSI_X
        df['Downward_Movement_SMMA'].iloc[RSI_X3:] = ((df['Downward_Movement_SMMA'].shift(1)*RSI_X2)+df['Downward_Movement'])/RSI_X

    df['RS'] = df['Upward_Movement_SMMA']/df['Downward_Movement_SMMA']
    df['RSI'] = 100-100/(df['RS']+1)
```

#Get TA RSI

```
    df['RSI_Ta'] = ta.RSI(df['Close'], timeperiod=14)
```

#Results

```
    print(df[['RSI', 'RSI_Ta']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method 2 (with exponential weighting) should give you the same values as talib.RSI, if you use following parameter to ewm function:

```
.ewm(alpha=1/period).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to re-produce the talib results in my own python function. Examining the talib source it looks like they do a simple average for the first period and then a smoothed moving average from that point forward. Perhaps they are trying to improve the stability early on. The below function should produce the same results as talib where the input and output is a numpy array:

```py
# note using jit siginificantly speeds up this function making it as fast as talib
#from numba import jit
#@jit(nopython=True)
def rsi(r, p=14):
    diffs = (r[1:]- r[:-1])
    l, g = 0, 0
    out = np.empty(r.shape,dtype=r.dtype)
    a = 1 - 1 / p
    for ind, d in enumerate(diffs):
        # for consistency with talib only start decay after first period
        if ind >= p:
            g *= a
            l *= a
        if d > 0:
            g += d / p
        else:
            l -= d / p
        div = l + g
        if div == 0:
            out[ind +1] = 50
        else:
            out[ind +1] = (100*g)/ div
    out[:p] = np.nan
    return out
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).